# Pick multiple images in react native Expo with Imagepicker

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, imagepicker

It seems like Expo only supports imagepicker for selecting one image rather than multiple images. Is there any way to pick multiple images without ejecting expo or starting new react-native-init?

Comment: Look at https://github.com/polycarpou/expo-camera-roll-select, may be need make changes  if you  are using expo 33+

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the link from Oleg working? 
I found that library as well, updated the Expo/SDK version because it was to old but now I get the following message when trying to open the gallery;

Invalid filter option: '(null)'. Expected one of photos, video's or all. To me unfortunately it is unclear where to place this filter exactly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7jV.png)